# Swift generic problem with array and individual item generic support

Tags: swift, generics

I have problem with declaring an Array and initialize it with many different generic items and in the same time use those items individually with generic support. Lets look at this:

```
protocol Item {
    associatedtype ValueType: Any
    var value: ValueType? { get set }
}
class ItemClass<T: Any>: Item {
    typealias ValueType = T
    var value: ValueType?
}

let intItem = ItemClass<Int>()
let stringItem = ItemClass<String>()
let array: [ItemClass<Any>] = [intItem, stringItem]

// Iterate over items and use `value` property as Any?
for item in array {
    let val: Any? = item.value
    // do something with val
}

// Individual usage with generic types support
let intValue: Int? = intItem.value
let stringValue: String? = stringItem.value
```

Why there is an error in array declaration like this:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ItemClass<Int>' to expected element type 'ItemClass<Any>'
```

Comment: That's because Swift generic types are not covariant. `ItemClass<Any>` and `ItemClass<Int>` are completely unrelated types.

Comment: So How I can declare Array this way so I have access to value: Any property of each items. I know each items should contain `value` property but since this is in array I can have different types of this property that should cast to `Any`.

Comment: If I declare array like this: `let array: [ItemClass] = ...` then I have the same problem. I know I'm casting `ItemClass<Int>` to `ItemClass`. I can not use `let array: [Item]` because of `Protocol 'Item' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. I don't know what to do in this situation.

Comment: What you're trying to implement with `ItemClass` is called type erasure, but even that won't help, since even with a type erased `AnyItem` type, you'll only be able to store `Item`s in an `Array` whose `value` property is of the same type. What you are trying to achieve isn't possible with your current setup. Why is `item` even a `protocol`? Why isn't it simply a generic `struct` in the first place? If your real problem is more complex than this, then include your real problem, not a contrived example.

Answer (score 1):

This entire approach is incorrect, and you can see that by the consuming code:

```
// Iterate over items and use `value` property as Any?
for item in array {
    let val: Any? = item.value
    // do something with val
}
```

In that "do something with val," what can you possibly do? There are no methods on `Any`. If you're going to do something like `as? T`, then you've broken the whole point of the types, because you don't mean "any". You mean "some list of types I know about." If you want "some list of types I know about," that's an enum with associated data, not a protocol with an associated type.

```
enum Item {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)

    var stringValue: String? {
        guard case .string(let value) = self else { return nil }
        return value
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        guard case .int(let value) = self else { return nil }
        return value
    }
}

let intItem = Item.int(4)
let stringItem = Item.string("value")
let array: [Item] = [intItem, stringItem]

// Iterate over items and use `value` property as Any?
for item in array {
    switch item {
    case let .string(value): break // Do something with string
    case let .int(value): break // Do something with int
    }
}

// Individual usage with generic types support
let intValue: Int? = intItem.intValue
let stringValue: String? = stringItem.stringValue
```

If, on the other hand, you really mean "any type," then you're not going to be able to put them in a collection without hiding the values in a box that gets rid of any information about that type (i.e. "a type eraser"). Which you need comes down to your actual use case. There isn't a single answer; it's going to be driven by how you want to consume this data.

But if you need `as?` very much at all, you've done something wrong.